# How to transpose values from certain columns in google form, [ignore those with blank values] into part of email htmlBody using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Dear Helpful Contributors,
I'm trying to fetch values from certain columns (column D to I as shown in screenshot below)) from a response gsheet.
[image]

For each submission of google form, I need to fetch those values of Stocktake Item1 until Item 6, transpose them so that the values will be diplayed in htmlBody of an email like below screenshot :-
[image]

Those Stocktake Item with zero values should not be displayed. So, each record may have different values for each Stocktake Item but only those with non-blanks or non-zero only should be displayed.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

At the moment, I only can achieve the goal on displaying them all regardless zeros or not. The way I'm doing this at the moment is by creating a table in another gsheet then using script to copy the values from each column of the Stocktake Item in the response sheet into that table accordingly. Then I created html template to convert that table into html.  Please refer to the screenshot of my current table in sheet 'stocktake' below.
[image]

My current code is as below:-

```
function gsheet2html() {
  const respsheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c0-vzYQA_9KVHuGHKiYS-3iBBGhTg3EcCZBm7rZDIpM").getSheetByName('response');//input from gform
  const stocksheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c0-vzYQA_9KVHuGHKiYS-3iBBGhTg3EcCZBm7rZDIpM").getSheetByName('stocktake'); //template
  
  const lrow=respsheet.getLastRow();
  const lr=stocksheet.getLastRow();
  var stockdate=respsheet.getRange(lrow,11).getValue();
  
  for(var i=4;i<lr-1;i++){
  stocksheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(respsheet.getRange(lrow,i).getValue());
  stocksheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(stockdate); 
  }
   
  const headers=stocksheet.getRange("A3:C3").getValues();
  const descr=headers[0][0];
  const qty=headers[0][1];
  const date=headers[0][2];
 
  const tableRangeValues=stocksheet.getRange(2,1,lr-2,3).getDisplayValues();
  const total=stocksheet.getRange(lr,1,1,2).getDisplayValues();
  const totalText=total[0][0];
  const totalSum=total[0][1];
  
  const htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("report");
  htmlTemplate.descr=descr;
  htmlTemplate.qty=qty;
  htmlTemplate.date=date;
  htmlTemplate.stockdate=stockdate;
  htmlTemplate.totalText=totalText;
  htmlTemplate.totalSum=totalSum;
  htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues=tableRangeValues;
  
  const htmlForEmail=htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  console.log(htmlForEmail);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    "testesttest@gmail.com",
    "Your Monthly Report",
    "Please open this email with HTML support",
    {htmlBody:htmlForEmail}
  );
}
```

My HTML code for the email body (html file : 'report') is currently as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <br>Dear Mr. PIC,
 <br>
 <br>Stocktake for today for your kind perusal.
 <br>
 <br>
  <div style="background-color:purple;height:4px;"></div>
  
<table>
<thead>
<tr style="text-align:center;padding:6px;color:purple;font-size:16px;">
<th ><?=descr?></th><th><?=qty?></th><th><?=date?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?tableRangeValues.forEach((r,i)=>{
let color;
if(i%2===0){color="light-grey"} else{color="white"}?>
<tr style="background-color:<?=color?>;">
<td style="text-align:left;padding:6px;"><?=r[0]?></td>
<td style="text-align:right;padding:6px;"><?=r[1]?></td>
<td style="text-align:center;padding:6px;"><?=r[2]?></td>
</tr>
<?})?>

</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr style="color:purple; font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
<td style="text-align:left;"><?=totalText?></td><td style="text-align:right;"><?=totalSum?></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<br>
<br>Thank you.
<br>
<br>Yours Sincerely,
<br>Somebody@Work
</body>
</html>
```

But with this method, all the Stocktake Items are fixed, so each time I produced the html email, it will always shows all the Socktake Item as per tabulated. I'm tasked to omit the items with zero values.  So far I cannot use that fixed table to dynamically omit those items with zero values. I'm thinking theoritically it should be somehow by fetching the values direct from response sheet, validate those non-zeroes values only to be in an array, transpose them in html template. But I just don't know how to code that. I only found GAS that shows to transpose all values from a response sheet, not selective ones only.

Hopefully my problem statement is clearer this time and hopefully someone can have the solution for this.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: From your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `<td><?=row[0]?></td><td><?=row[1]?><?=row[2]?></td><td><?=row[3]?></td>` and your expected result. I apologize for my poor understanding. Can you provide the sample values of `tableRangeValues`?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. It's kinda challenging to explain my problem in words than to show directly. However, let me try to rephrase the content of my question above.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It seems that in your script, `tableRangeValues` creates the table. So I thought that when the sample value of `tableRangeValues` is provided, it will also help to think of the solution. And I thought that to preprocess the value of `tableRangeValues` might be suitable for achieving your goal. How about this?

Comment: You're most welcome,@Tanaike. I just finished my edited version of my question. i hope that clarifies better.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately,  from `I only can achieve the goal on displaying them all regardless zeros or not.`, I cannot image your current script for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. By this, I cannot image the value of `tableRangeValues`. In order to correctly understand about your current situation and your goal, can you provide your current script? And also, can you provide the sample value of `tableRangeValues`?

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry took me a while. I just managed to produce the code based on sampling data. I've edited my question which includes my code and the tableRangeValues as per requested.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

When `stockdate` sheet has the values of "A3:C10" like your 3rd image, in your script, `tableRangeValues` is the values from "A2:C9" which is `stocksheet.getRange(2,1,lr-2,3).getDisplayValues()`. By this, when I saw your 3rd image, the empty row and header row are included in `tableRangeValues`. So I think that your script might different from your actual situation. I'm worry about this.

So it supposes that when at your actual situation, `tableRangeValues` is the following values,

```
Stock Item1       9/20/2020
Stock Item2       9/20/2020
Stock Item3   6   9/20/2020
Stock Item4       9/20/2020
Stock Item5   7   9/20/2020
Stock Item6   8   9/20/2020
```

how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues=tableRangeValues;
```

#### To:

```
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues.filter(([,b]) => b.toString() != "");
```

or

```
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues.filter(function(e) {return e[1].toString() != ""});
```

#### Note:

- When your actual situation is the same with your 3rd image and this modified script is used and 2 header rows are shown in HTML, please modify as follows and test it again. In this modification, the values are retrieved from `A4:C9`.

  - From

    ```
      const tableRangeValues=stocksheet.getRange(2,1,lr-2,3).getDisplayValues();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const tableRangeValues=stocksheet.getRange(4,1,lr-4,3).getDisplayValues();
    ```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you for your swift response, @Tanaike. I will try it now and update you soon.

Comment: tq soooo much for your solution and corrections! I didn't realized the wrong references as I didn't realized it has caused the headers to be double 'printed' and I didn't think I could utilize back the gsheet template 'stocksheet' to achieve this! BIG tq,@Tanaike!! You saved the day!